# disable SSL on MAMP

Tags: ssl, localhost, mamp

Hi I'm used to editing sites locally on my MAMP to test out changes before going live. In this case though the site has a SSL certificate and wants to use it when I go to admin.

So I can't go to admin. The error message says:

```
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

It's a Joomla site I'm trying to log into locally ie:

http://localhost:8888/site/administrator/

I've tried https as well, but same thing. Also same thing is Safari.

I just need to turn off ssl, it must be a file somewhere in the site I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've answered my own question. I just had to disable the default Joomla seo urls in the Joomla config file. No sure why it fixed it though